# Improve True Negative of unbalanced dataset

Tags: classification

How can I improve the model's ability to predict rare classes given the objective of predicting rare class accurately? I have a dataset with binary target variable. I tested a few models but still despite the model's accuracy being high, it is unable to predict any True Negative and False Negative (both have value of 0). I have tried resampling strategies but it does not have an impact on TN and FN, rather the accuracy decreases.

Comment: If you want to catch the rare class, why not just predict it every time? You’ll never miss another instance!

Comment: The real problem is likely with the features: they are not good enough for the model to reliably distinguish the positive and negative class, so in doubt it predicts the most common class,

Comment: did you determine unbalanced data by analyzing a confusion matrix?  Please post the code for determine data imbalance.  Have you tried a bidirectional lstm with binary_crossentropy?

Comment: @GoldenLion You need predictions to form a confusion matrix. Class imbalance depends on the data, not the predictions. // Why LSTM? I do not see any mention of sequential data.

Comment: What model would you use?  You could use a dense network.  LSTM is not a requirement, but it is a possibility.  I have created heatmaps using confusion matrix from a dense network, in the past.   how did you detect imbalance? post your code please

Comment: The particular model would depend on the data and the goals, but the model choice is not (or at least is minimally) related to the existence of class imbalance, which is assessed just by looking at the class frequencies.

Comment: start with logistic regression.  I believe logistic regression, random forest and xgboost are all you ever need in machine learning.  DNN are very complex and costly to get a slight advantage.

Answer (score 1):

Using Bayes’ theorem, the predictions are affected by the [prior probability](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/583115/247274) of the classes. When you use a cutoff threshold of $0.5$, it might be that you never predict that high of a probability of being in the minority class, so you never classify in the minority class.

This alludes to the [many problems](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6349/247274) with threshold-based metrics that often have their most dramatic effects in imbalanced situations.

A simple approach is to change the threshold, with the extreme being my suggestion in the comments to classify everything as the minority class. This is why ROCAUC is a popular, even if [problematic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a4253%20roc) metric, as it considers performance at all thresholds.

A more sophisticated approach would be to ditch thresholds and evaluate the probability outputs with the strictly proper scoring rules discussed in some of those links in that [Cross Validated Meta post.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6349/247274) Frank Harrell, founding chair of biostatistics at Vanderbilt University, has two good blog posts on probability predictions, too.

[Damage Caused by Classification Accuracy and Other Discontinuous Improper Accuracy Scoring Rules](https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/)

[Classification vs. Prediction](https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to handle :

- In cost function, increase weight for instances of minority class
- while minimizing cost function, take recall as your performance criterion

Answer (score 0):

Behind the scenes of most machine learning algorithms there is a confidence score associated to the models prediction. For sklearn you can retrieve them using model_name.predict_prob instead of model_name.predict. By default most models predict uses a .5 confidence score, i.e. anything above a .5 confidence score is predicted to be in the positive class. All you have to do is alter that threshold and you can tradeoff performance between the two classes.

You can also try various methods for making the model "see" a more balanced dataset - upsampling, downsampling, SMOTE, and class sensitive weighting.